# What should I do with Hybrid_Endpoint::process() when migrating from 2.xx to 3.xx?

Tags: hybridauth

I'm trying to migrate a project from HybridAuth 2.xx to 3.00, and I'm facing an issue with the following call to "Hybrid_Endpoint":

```
require_once( "Hybrid/Auth.php" );
require_once( "Hybrid/Endpoint.php" );
Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
```

I haven't seen that too much in the 2.xx documentation, but it appears quite a lot in many examples on the web, as well as in the code I try to migrate.

Apparently, in [my code](https://github.com/alixandru/q2a-open-login/blob/master/qa-open-login.php), there's either a login or process (the first calls authenticate(...) and the second process(...)

Should I just comment that part ? Not clear from the [migration guide](https://hybridauth.github.io/developer-ref-migrating.html)!

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find the answer by trial and error. The short answer, it's not needed anymore - the "process" method is now integrated in the authenticate() method (which now serves two purposes: redirect and process), as described in the examples: https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/tree/master/examples